# Not able to execute with clause in dynamic sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to execute below statement using dynamic SQL but I'm getting this exception

> "ORA-00911: 
>   invalid character on ORA-06512".

When i remove **semicolon(;)** the query runs but it's taking a long time and is not able to display output.

How do I clear this problem? Is anywhere I'm doing wrong? if so please guide me.

Below is my code:

```
DECLARE    
   mapping_rule     VARCHAR2 (10000)
      := 'SALES_REVIEW.NET_VALUE-SALES_REVIEW.GROSS_VALUE+SALES_REVIEW_TABLE.PLNT';
   v_mapp_rule      VARCHAR2 (10000);    
   v_mapp_rule_1    VARCHAR2 (10000);    
   v_chk_flag       CHAR (1) := 'Y';
   v_mapping_rule   VARCHAR2 (10000);
   v_str            VARCHAR2 (30000);
BEGIN
  <<dest_stmt>>
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (v_chk_flag);

   IF v_chk_flag = 'Y'
   THEN
      v_mapping_rule := mapping_rule;
   ELSE
      v_mapping_rule := v_mapp_rule_1;
   END IF;

   v_str :=
      'WITH sel_col (rowno, mapp_rule)
        AS (    SELECT ROWNUM rowno,
                       REGEXP_SUBSTR (  ''' || v_mapping_rule
      || ''',''([+--*!@/#$%^&()=<>,?]+|[A-Z0-9_.'''']+|\s+)'',
                          1,
                          LEVEL)
                          mapp_rule
                  FROM DUAL
            CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR ('''
      || v_mapping_rule
      || ''',''([+--*!@/#$%^&()=<>,?]+|[A-Z0-9_.'''']+|\s+)'',
                          1,
                          LEVEL)
                          IS NOT NULL)
     SELECT listagg (
               CASE WHEN B.MAPP_RULE IS NOT NULL THEN B.MAPP_RULE 
                    ELSE D.MAPP_RULE END,
               '''')
            WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY d.rowno)
       FROM RRR_PROCESS_DTLS a
            JOIN RRR_PROCESS_MAPPING_DTLS b
               ON A.PROCESS_ID = B.PROCESS_ID 
                  AND A.COMPANY_ID = B.COMPANY_ID
            JOIN RRR_DEST_TABLE_DTLS C
               ON A.DEST_TABLE = C.TABLE_ID 
                  AND A.COMPANY_ID = C.COMPANY_ID
            RIGHT JOIN sel_col d
               ON CONCAT (CONCAT (C.TABLE_NAME, ''.''), B.DEST_COLUMN) =
                     d.mapp_rule
                  AND A.PROCESS_ID = 12 
                  AND A.COMPANY_ID = 2
   ORDER BY d.rowno;';

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (v_str);

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_str into v_mapp_rule_1 ;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('bf ' || v_mapp_rule_1);

   IF v_mapp_rule_1 IS NOT NULL
   THEN
      v_chk_flag := 'N';
      GOTO dest_stmt;
   END IF;    

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (v_mapp_rule_1);
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (
            SQLCODE
         || ' -ERROR- '
         || SQLERRM
         || ' on '
         || DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE);
END;
```

Comment: The semi-colon is incorrect, that't why you get the ORA error.  Once removed, the dynamic SQL can be run and apparently takes a long time.  Why not try running (or running `explain plan` on) the SQL run normally, rather than through a PL/SQL block with dynamic SQL? Maybe the reason will then become apparent.

Comment: Thnaks Tony.. The reason i'm going with pl/sql dynamic sql, In normal SQL it will work fine, In my scenario i never know the "mapping_rule", the input will change every call of this block(once this work fine, In future will make it as procedure/function).

Comment: Try running the query outside the PL/SQL block, passing the value of mapping_rule,verifying it runs fine. Only then use it in a dynamic block ;that too if required.

Comment: Hi Kaushik, I have tried that too also that running fine, when i try to making dynamic there only the problem.

Comment: Hi Tony, Kaushik, I got where the problem casing on above code and i cleared that too also.the problem was, after the select stmt, i have been using if condition, that checks the "v_mapp_rule_1" is not null , if it is TRUE, this label statement will be executed, Here the problem was, In select statement i won't null value to failed if stmt for every call because i am taking input "d.mapp_rule" in case of NULL on select stmt. for every call of the select statement will get some value and the label statement also will keep execute until if is FALSE , that was pbm casued, that's fr ur suggestion.

Comment: You should use @ symbol before the names . Otherwise, it won't be received as a message by the user. Glad to know you found out the problem.